# Dynamically switch flex size in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

i am trying to switch the flex size using Vuejs. I have three radio buttons and a select. How do i make it such that when i Select on XS4 radio button, the select takes flex size of XS4. Same for XS6 and XS12 respectively.

I have created a Codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/agzoNE.

```
    <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-radio-group row v-model="radioGroup">
    <v-radio label="XS4" value="XS4"></v-radio>
    <v-radio label="XS6" value="XS6"></v-radio>
    <v-radio label="XS12" value="XS12"></v-radio>
     </v-radio-group>
  <v-select placeholder="How to Dynamically change the flex size for this 
select?"></v-select>
</v-app>
</div>


  new Vue({
  el:'#app',
   data(){
   return{
    radioGroup: 1,
  }
 }
 })
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So change the value of the radios to lowercase, wrap the `v-select` with `v-layout` and `v-flex`, and then bind the class of the `v-flex` to `radioGroup`.

```
<v-layout row>
    <v-flex :class="radioGroup">
        <v-select placeholder="How to Dynamically change the flex size for this select?" ></v-select>
    </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqEBpw?editors=1111)

Comment: Ohhh i see where i was going wrong. thank You so much :)